# upgrade tomcat version on amazon aws

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I use amazon aws to host my website. Elastic Beanstalk config.

I needed to upgrade the tomcat version from the ancient 7.0.23 to 7.0.69

I ran

**`sudo yum update`**

then

**`sudo yum install tomcat7`**

then

**`yum info tomcat7`**

and it confirmed the version as-

**`Version     : 7.0.69`**

however,

If I run **`./version.sh** in **/opt/tomcat7/bin/`**

I get

**`Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.23`**

How do I force the default tomcat version to be 7.0.69?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was trying to do was increment the tomcat version on an aws elastic beanstalk **legacy** environment.

This is not best practice. I had to build a new elastic beanstalk environment and migrate over to the new environment.

I built the new environment to my new baseline, however future upgrades can now be managed appropriately.

I think the communications from AWS on this could be a lot stronger about when an environment becomes legacy, implications of this - and the recommended best practice to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

When upgrading instances of Apache Tomcat from one version of Tomcat 7 to another, particularly when using separate locations for $CATALINA_HOME and $CATALINA_BASE, it is necessary to ensure that any changes in the configuration files such as new attributes and changes to defaults are applied as part of the upgrade. To assist with the identification of these changes, the form in below link may be used to view the differences between the configuration files in different versions of Tomcat 7.

http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html#Upgrading_7.0.x

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I was hoping to perform this with an amazon aws managed upgrade. There is a juicy looking button next to 32bit Amazon Linux running Tomcat 7 (legacy) on the elastic beanstalk ui but it is greyed out.

Comment: Sorry to bother you error2007s but do you think the above tomcat upgrade steps are a legitimate approach. Would you have expected them to work?

Comment: Which one the one in the question or one in my answer?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you saying the sudo yum install doesn't take into account the config file changes as part of the upgrade. There are two catalina.policy files /etc/tomcat7/catalina.policy and /opt/tomcat7/conf/catalina.policy. Am I right in guessing it would be the one in etc that I would need to change. Separate to the install? The sudo yum install doesn't appear to fail though. Is it supposed to update the one in /opt/tomcat at the same time?

Comment: Yes you will need to update the one in ETC and then restart Apache

Comment: Thanks will give that a go.